# why does Hyperledger Fabric install chaincode by compiling source code rather than binary?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hyperledger Fabric installs chaincode on several peers with the chaincode package which includes the compressed source code, and compile it in the ccenv docker container launched by the process of chaincode instantiation. I am wondering why it does not directly install the binary in the container for those peers. Any special purpose? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling chaincode within `ccenv` container ensures that outcome will be the same for all participants in the network, otherwise there might be an issues and diffs caused by differences of compilers version, dependencies available and etc. This is also necessary for cross platform compilation.

Comment: Thank you Artem Barger. I understand the compilation would ensure the outcome will be the same for all participants. But it can be achieved as well by installing the same binary of chaincode in the ccenv docker container which is the same runtime environment for those peers. So why compiling source code is better than installing the same binary?

Comment: @R.L It is obvious, compiling is more stable and consistent. Installing will need network which may fluctuate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is, all participating peers need to achieve agreements on the code (smart contract), with binary it would be harder to inspect what the code does.  Before a peer to endorse a chaincode installation proposal it supposes to inspect the content.